# Exception when trying to createOrUpdate an object using OrmLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I am working on an Android app that uses a the createOrUpdate method to add objects to the SQLite database.

This is the exception that is being thrown (inconsistently):

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException:attempt to write a
           readonly database (code 1032)
```

The manifest permissions do include WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

This exception seems to occur in 2 places, inconsistently, but each time when executing this try/catch:

```
try {
    getDatabaseHelper().getAccountDao().createOrUpdate(aAccount);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    CrashlyticsLog.e(LOGTAG, "Encountered a problem when attempting to synchronize local "
                     + "database with login response object", e);
}
```

We are retrieving our instance of DatabaseHelper from the Application class:

```
public DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper() {
   if (databaseHelper == null) {
      databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
   }
   return databaseHelper;
}
```

Here is the full stack trace (I changed the package name):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object com.example.Account@3bca6:
        INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id` ,`logo` ,`company` ,`subdomain` ,`plan_id` ,
        `plan_expires` ,`timezone_id` ,`timezone_name` ,`settings` ,`created_at`,
        `updated_at` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:124)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:394)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:308)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:334)
   at com.example.ui.account.AccountsActivity.loginUser(AccountsActivity.java:151)
   at com.example.ui.account.fragment.AccountListFragment.onListItemClick(AccountListFragment.java:240)
   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: inserting to database failed: INSERT INTO `accounts`
      (`id` ,`logo` ,`company` ,`subdomain` ,`plan_id` ,`plan_expires` ,`timezone_id`,
       `timezone_name` ,`settings` ,`created_at` ,`updated_at` )
       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
   at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:159)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:89)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:394)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:308)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:334)
   at com.thisclicks.wiw.ui.account.AccountsActivity.loginUser(AccountsActivity.java:151)
   at com.thisclicks.wiw.ui.account.fragment.AccountListFragment.onListItemClick(AccountListFragment.java:240)
   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a
      readonly database (code 1032)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
   at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:147)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:89)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:394)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:308)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:334)
   at com.example.ui.account.AccountsActivity.loginUser(AccountsActivity.java:151)
   at com.example.ui.account.fragment.AccountListFragment.onListItemClick(AccountListFragment.java:240)
   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've never seen this before.  Any chance your hardware is blocking writes to the database or something?  ORMLite is definitely asking for a read-write connection.

Comment: @Gray Thank you for your help. To answer your question, I am not quite sure- using Crashlytics to track this bug we can see it occurs for Android versions 4.4.2, 4.3, 4.4.4, as well as 5.0, and 5.1. Is there any other information I can provide?

Comment: Did you find the solution?